# Getting null value after Mocking the function

Tags: java, mockito

```
class Foo {
    ReturnParameters function1(int a, int b) {
        function2(a, b);
    }

    ReturnParameters function2(int a , int b) {
        // body of this function...
   }
}
```

I am creating a Junit test with Mockito and only want to test **function1()** and want to mock the returns from **function2()**

Below is my TestCase Class

```
class FooTest{
    Foo foo = mock(Foo.class);

    @Test
    public void function1test(){
        Mockito.when(foo.function2(1,2)).thenReturn(new ReturnParameters(100));
        ReturnParameters actualResult = foo.function1(1,2);
        int expectedResult = 100;
        AssertEquals(expectedResult , actualResult.getStatus());
    }
}
```

I am getting this error message that ***actualResult*** is a null value.

Can you please help?

Comment: does `new ReturnParameters(100)` set the `status` field?

Comment: You can try spying the object. Doing this you will be able to mock selective methods. here's an article for your reference: https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-spy

Comment: Does the error say that `actualResult` is null or what `getStatus` returns?

Comment: if you want to mock some functions in a class you can use a spy instead of a mock. Because you dont want to mock the whole object but the return value of one method of it.

Comment: does new ReturnParameters(100) set the status field? - YES

Comment: "Does the error say that actualResult is null or what getStatus returns?" - Actual result is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to partially stub the methods in a class.
In order to do this, you must use Spy instead of Mock.

Here is some sample code (that assumes you are using Junit5 and uses doReturn.when instead of when.thenReturn):

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class TestFoo
{
    @Spy
    private Foo spyClassToTest;
    
    @BeforeEach
    public void before()
    {
        // stub the function 2 call.  The function 1 call is still "live"
        doReturn(new ReturnParameters(100)).when(spyClassToTest).function2(1, 2);
    }

    @Test
    public void function1_descriptionOfTheTestScenario_returns100()
    {
        ReturnParameters actualResult;
        int expectedResult = 100;

        // Perform the test
        actualResult = spyClassToTest.function1(1, 2);
        
        assertNotNull(actualResult);
        assertEquals(expectedResult, actualResult.getStatus());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the domain but maybe its a good idea to split your functions into different classes. It should solve this issue in a clean way. Spy should also work though.